# "make this right" phrase

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request

I wrote

> If Saudi Arabia, and the US and Israel, as its allies, are destabilizing the region by funding and supporting radical groups, why doesn't this make Russia and Iran right in countering this move (from the Middle Easterns' viewpoints)?

Is it an idiomatic usage "make somebody right in doing something"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That some action is **made** right or appropriate by some hypothetical fact or condition is a rhetorical *legerdemain*.  You're going from a hypothetical or conditional to a declarative, from **if**, to **makes**.

You also have too many **this**es  so your sentence is like a traffic cop in Rome.

> **If** Saudi Arabia and the US and Israel as its allies are destabilizing
>   the region by funding and supporting radical groups, why **wouldn't**
>   Russia and Iran **be** justified in countering that move?

If you wanted to use **make right** in the sense of to justify an action:

> Saudi Arabia and the US and Israel as its allies are destabilizing the region by funding and supporting radical groups. Do these concerted efforts to destabilize the region not make it right for Russia and Iran to counter them?

But that rhetorical question is involuted, since you're asking if the concerted efforts themselves justify attempts to counter them.  Why cast those concerted efforts as the subject of **make**?  Of course, you're referring to the *fact* of those concerted efforts, *that they are underway*, not to those efforts per se.

So you might as well be forthright and pose the question like this:

> **When** Saudi Arabia and the US and Israel as its allies are destabilizing the region by funding and supporting radical groups, are not Russia and Iran  justified in countering those concerted efforts?